# Django query, find latest version of self excluding unpublished versions

Tags: django, django-models

Abbreviating my code, I have two tables:

```
Article:
  title = ...

ArticleVersion:
  article = ForeignKey(Article)
  version = IntegerField
  datetime_published = DatetimeField(null=True)
```

An `ArticleVersion` is *unpublished* if it's `datetime_published` field is `null`.

I need to find the *max published version* for *all ArticleVersion* objects.

What I have so far that works for `ArticleVersion` objects in any published state is:

```
ArticleVersion.objects \
    .select_related('article') \
    .annotate(max_version=Max('article__articleversion__version')) \
    .filter(version=F('max_version'))
```

But I'm having difficulty filtering that relation `article__articleversion__version` to only `ArticleVersion` objects with a non-null `datetime_published` value.

`.exclude(datetime_published=None)` doesn't work and neither does `.exclude(article__articleversion__datetime_published=None)` anywhere within the query.

I'd prefer to not use raw SQL and keep it within a single query if at all possible.

Any help?

EDIT: if it wasn't clear, the problem is that `article__articleversion__version` is annotating with *unpublished* max `ArticleVersion.version` values. Excluding when `datetime_published` is `null` then excludes results whose versions don't exactly equal the max version value calculated on unpublished results.

Comment: Have you tried using the `__isnull` filtering? In your case, `.exclude(datetime_published__isnull=True)`

Comment: see edit. the problem is that article__articleversion__version is annotating with unpublished max ArticleVersion.version values.